# Loading local JSON file in React for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Im trying to figure out the best way of accessing the local JSON file and storing it in my current state. I hope i am in the right track :)

**Project.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

// framer motion
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

const Project = (props) => {
const { projectID } = useParams();
const [project, setProject] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('src/data/projects.json', {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <motion.div exit={{ opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 1 } }}></motion.div>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

**JSON FILE**

```
[
{
  "title": "Example",
  "id": "1",
  "src": "example.png"
},
{
  "title": "Example 2",
  "id": "2",
  "src": "example-2.png"
}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log({res})`? Maybe JSON itself is not in a valid format.

Comment: Can you try to remove comma after the second object? This is a stupid guess while I'm trying with the live code.

Comment: May i know why you are using fetch to load local `json file`? you can just import the `json` data normally using `import`

Comment: @SifatHaque : I don't see any problem fetching json data this way as well :)

Comment: @jmvdc check this article [Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/)

Comment: I'm trying a different method. So it means that i can just use the local file and then filter out the JSON and then set the returned object in the current state?

Comment: @jmvdc: I believe your relative path is incorrect :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather ya that's what I'm thinking what should i put in the fetch url?

Comment: Can you share you folder structure in the form of an image :)

Comment: Let me see  check this

Comment: Is you Project.js directly within your components folder ?

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather it is inside the pages folder

Comment: Directly within pages Right Mate? If yes then you have your answer :)

Comment: Give it a try... In case this does not work. I would like to see the pages folder also :)

Comment: @jmvdc: Please check the final answer now... I have also added a DEMO link to point out the problem :) Hope this helps :) I think we must thank Sifat as well for pointing it out:)

Answer (score 5):

This clearly looks like your relative path is not correct.

**UPDATE:** From the comments and cross checking it is clear that we must move our json file into a public folder for it to work.

So you need to first do that and directly use this path:

```
fetch('data/projects.json',
```

**HERE IS THE DEMO:** https://codesandbox.io/s/json-fanda-stydg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: typo my bad bro.

Comment: Could you show your pages directory image ?

Comment: Let me see Mate

Comment: This should technically work :) Can you create a sandbox for this one. And share the link with me... Or just to check it is working try removing header stuff from fetch...

Comment: fetch("./../data/projects.json'')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));

Comment: Also for now.... Just return <div>Testing ...</div> from your return. We'll just debug for data :)

Comment: should i move the json file to my public directory?

Comment: Just give me a moment :) I will try cross checking this in sandbox :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather add `export default` before function to make the code valid.

Comment: Hey Luka Mate... My Bad !!! Actually I converted class component into functional one and forgot to export :) Done now ... Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `import` to load `json data` and then use them.

To `fetch` data you `need to` upload your file in `public` folder. Then you can easily load that `json data`.  Here is the [link of working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-voice-kijr7?file=/src/App.js).

**Make sure you've uploaded your data inside public folder. Otherwise it won't work.**

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  const fetchJSONDataFrom = useCallback(async (path) => {
    const response = await fetch(path, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setProjects(data);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJSONDataFrom("data/projects.json");
  }, [fetchJSONDataFrom]);
```

Comment: But Technically that's not needed at all :) We can have data anywhere and we can fetch anytime :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather may be create react app is configured in such way. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Yup :) I checked it as well. It is working well with public folder

Comment: @jmvdc glad that it helps. Please don't hesitate to upvote or set this as accepted answer. May be this will help others as well :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Directly import json file (without using fetch).

```
import data from 'src/data/projects.json';
```

Stringify and parse data like this:

```
const loadedData = JSON.stringify(data);
const json = JSON.parse(loadedData);
```

Now you have `json` variable as valid array containing your data.

Comment: That's not needed at all.  Even if this is done, then first we need to export the JSON data first :)

Comment: I already have a solution without using fetch but i'm trying to figure this out using promises

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather I was not exporting it. What do you mean by that? I created plain `.json` file (without creating a const and exporting it) with the data provided above and then just imported that file under the name of `data`. Maybe I'm making some cardinal mistake.

Comment: Ya your point is also valid... My bad. It's when we use .js extension in data. That we have to export it :)